# Access Go To Next Record with Matching Foreign Key

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to find a way in MS Access 2016 when I search for the next record it goes to the next record with the same matching foreign key. The records are not next to each other in the table and want to be able to move back and forth to edit information regarding a specific foreign key that has been searched.

To add, I'm hoping to keep this in Form View and use buttons similar to previous record and next record to move back and forth between records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be done in Macro Builder or VBA; however, going to explain how to do this in Macro Builder. You may go to the Source Link at the bottom to find out how to use the command in VBA.

1) Use the Find Record command to get to the information that you want to edit.

2) Next, program the button that you want to go to the next record that is related to the Foreign Key.

Create a Temp Variable that equals your Foreign Key with SetTempVar as the first event in the Macro Builder.

After this, use the following command in macro builder: FindRecord … Next, set the properties of the Find Record command.

Find What: =[TempVars]![***TempVariableNameHere***]

Then set the rest of the form to what you want to tailor it to.

Source:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-findrecord-method-access

Answer (score 0):

Use a form in datasheet view where you filter on that specific foreign key.

Then you can move back and forth and edit as much as you like.

Right-click on a record with the foreign key of the records to edit. Select Filter on the value.

Now you can navigate using the normal record navigation buttons.

Comment: Hi, I am hoping to keep it in Form View, if I can. I'm wondering if there is a macro or VBA script that can accomplish what I'm looking for.

Comment: OK. Should be easy with no macro or code at all. See edited answer, please.

Comment: Hi Gustav, your answer to me seems like an easy answer for someone that knows a little bit about MS Access; however, most of the people that are going to be using this database is for data entry purposes and need to be stream lined for our use. The solution I have found is to have the main form on the left hand that can be edited while having a subform on the right hand side that is set to table view of the current person's records. I have locked down the subform so it can only be viewed and not edited from that location. I appreciate you trying to offer other solutions.